# How can we show this equality?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $N\trianglelefteq G$ and $f: G\rightarrow H$ a group epimorphism with $N\cap \text{Ker}(f)=1$.

If $x\in N$ I want to show that $f(C_G(x))=C_H(f(x))$.

Could you give me some hints how we could show that?

We have that $$C_G(X)=\{g\in G\mid gx=xg ,  \forall x\in X\}$$

Is at the equality that we want to prove the $x$ a set or an element?

Comment: What do $C_G$ and $C_H$ mean?

Comment: I added the definition in my initial post... @ajotatxe

Answer (score 1):

Double contention:

$$g\in C_G(x)\implies f(g)\in f(C_G(x))\;,\;\;\text{and}\;\; gx=xg\implies f(g)f(x)=f(x)f(g)\implies$$

$$f(g)\in C_H(f(x))\implies f(C_G(x))\subset C_H(f(x))$$

And now the other way around

$$h\in C_H(f(x))\implies hf(x)=f(x)h. \text{let}\;\;g\in G\;\;\text{such that}\;\;f(g)=h\implies$$

$$f(g)f(x)=f(x)f(g)\implies f(gx)=f(xg)\implies f\left(gxg^{-1}x^{-1}\right)=1\implies$$

$$gxg^{-1}x^{-1}\in\ker f$$

But also $\;gxg^{-1}x=\left[gxg^{-1}\right]x^{-1}\in N\;$ , since $\;N\lhd G\;$ , so

$$gxg^{-1}x^{-1}\in N\cap\ker f=1\implies gx=xg\implies f^{-1}(h)=g\in C_G(x)$$

and we have the other direction

Comment: Why does it stand that $$g\in C_G(x)\implies f(g)\in f(C_G(x))$$ ?

Comment: @MaryStar That is just set theory:$$x\in X\implies f(x)\in f(X)$$

Comment: Do we suppose that $g\in C_G(x)$ ?

Comment: At the beginning of the proof, yes @MaryStar. Second line. At the end of the proof that what we show.

Comment: Ah ok... Why does the following implication hold? $$gx=xg\implies f(g)f(x)=f(x)f(g)$$ Is it because $f$ is an epimorphism?

Comment: @MaryStar Yes, indeed so.

Comment: To clarify... An epimorphism is an homomorphism that is surjective, or not?

Comment: @MaryStar Yes...

Comment: Why does the following implication hold? $$f(gx)=f(xg)\implies f\left(gxg^{-1}x^{-1}\right)=1$$

Comment: Does it stand that $$(xg)^{-1}=x^{-1}g^{-1}$$ or $$(xg)^{-1}=g^{-1}x^{-1}$$ ?

Comment: @MaryStar  With all due respect I think you should read carefully the basics on group theory as you make many very basic, almost trivial questions which, in my opinion do not fit the level of this question. In any group it is always true the second option you wrote unless the given groups is abelian.

Answer (score 1):

$g$ is in the centraliser of $x$ if and only if $gxg^{-1}x^{-1}=e$.

$f(C_G(x))\subset C_H(f(x))$ is obvious.

For the reverse inclusion, let $h\in G_H(f(x))$. As we have a group epimorphism, we may write $h=f(k)$ for some $k\in G$. Thus we have
$$e_H=hf(x)h^{-1}f(x)^{-1}=f(kxk^{-1}x^{-1}),$$
which proves $kxk^{-1}x^{-1}\in\ker f$.

Now since $N$ is a normal subgroup, $kxk^{-1}\in N$, hence $kxk^{-1}x^{-1}\in N $. As  $N\cap\ker f$, $kxk^{-1}x^{-1}=e_G$, which proves $k\in C_G(x)$, and $h=f(k)\in f(C_G(x))$.

Comment: Why does the following stand? $$e_H=hf(x)h^{-1}f(x)^{-1}=f(kxk^{-1}x^{-1})$$ What is $k$ ?

Comment: Oh! sorry for the inconsistent notation. $k$ corresponds to the equality $h=f(k)$ (and not $f(g)$ as I initially wrote). I hope the equality is clear now.

Comment: We have that $$e_H=(hf(x))(hf(x))^{-1}$$ Does it stand that $$(hf(x))^{-1}=h^{-1}f(x)^{-1}$$ ? $$$$ Then since $h=f(k)$ we have $$e_H=(hf(x))(hf(x))^{-1}=hf(x)h^{-1}f(x)^{-1}=f(k)f(x)h^{-1}f(x)^{-1}$$ With what do we replace $h^{-1}$ ?

Comment: Sorry,  one more typo.  $h^{-1}=f(k)^{-1}=f(k^{-1}$ since  $f$ is a group homomorphism.